# navigate ecore model

Tags: java, eclipse, model, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

How do I navigate, programmatically in java, an Ecore model to extract the elements information?

Comment: Do you want to navigate to a specific element, or do you want to simply traverse the whole object graph and do something with every element?

Answer (score 1):

The best single resource on EMF is the ["Eclipse Modeling Framework"](http://www.informit.com/title/9780321331885) book (2nd edition).

@Pangea's answer links to the EObject interfaces.  But a better way to use a model instance is to use the generated interfaces.  If you read the ["A Tour of the Eclipse Modeling Framework"](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseEMF/article.html) article by Lars Vogel, it includes a simple example of accessing a model using the generated APIs.  And "the book" has a lot more on this subject.

Comment: I did not suggest the generated code because I believe it is a maintenance issue if the model keeps changing. The EObject API provides a generic interface much like Reflection API

Comment: @Pangea - you have the same problem using EObject, except that you get runtime exceptions instead of compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EObject's api like eContents(), eSet(), eGet() etc..or you can use oAW's xText.

EObject API: http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.emf.doc/references/javadoc/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/EObject.html

http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/